# Querying meteor js for diagnostics information

Tags: meteor, statsd

I have a Meteor JS app and a statsd deamon. StatsD deamon is collecting stats, currently I am exporting business specific stats to the statsd deamon. Now I am trying export diagnostics information for the meteor app(such as socket count, live sessions count, subscription count, ...). Is there a way to get such information from a meteor app. I searched but was not able to find any examples nor documentation of such.

Comment: A good start is to `console.log(Meteor)` on the server and inspect the `Meteor` global Object. It contains lots of easily accessible information. If you get stuck you can extend this question by specific information.

Comment: @Jankapunkt thanks for comment.. I'll try this and let you know whether this serves my purpose, so you can add this as a answer and I can accept it :)

Comment: From that object I can get the active session count. But I cannot not see any property to get the number of active subscriptions... 
No worries I found a solution...
Can you add this as a answer since this comment leads to the correct direction

Comment: It would be better if you post the answer yourself and describe the solution as detailed as possible. Maybe others will find this question by search engine and will be thankful. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question ;-)